# How can I enable 1 to 1 messaging with SendBird's Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, chat, messaging, sendbird

I want to know if it is possible to enable a one-to-one messaging feature in sendbird messaging android sdk.
The related documentation talks about groups messaging and open channels

Comment: i think private channels are the 1 to 1 channels , it's a channel that contains only 2 users

Comment: i made an error, it is open channels

Comment: try to read the docs here https://docs.sendbird.com/android/group_channel

Comment: did you get how you can do it ?!

Comment: Yes thanks you. I found what i wanted. I realized that i was reading the wrong doc